# Networking: PC >(WiFi)> Router >(100BaseT)> PC >(WiFi/USB)> iPhone Hotspot> Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, routing

I have two PCs at home that share my iPhone's internet connection via WiFi, and a hard-wired LAN that enables me to transfer data between the computers at higher speeds.  This works very well for me.
I also have a Nao robot that I borrow from Uni so I can do development work at home.  I step-up the SSID1 Network to mimic the network settings we have at Uni so I can move the robot between home and Uni without making any changes to it's settings.  I connect the Nao robot to my LAN using WiFi, as it is mobile, and am able to do everything I need to with it.

Since the SSID1 router is not connected to the Internet, I've noticed that the internal clock is wrong and all my timestamps are incorrect (1970's).  (I don't have the timestamp issue on my other computers since they get their time via my iPhone.) Thus I've been working of getting my SSID1 router to access the internet.  Being able to reach the internet from the robot would also make some tasks a little easier.

I have tried a number of different approaches to get the SSID1 router to gain access to the Internet, but I haven't been able to achieve it yet.  The diagram below describes my setup.

[image: screenshot]

- PC1 is a Win7 based machine and is my main computer.
- PC2 is a MacBook Pro that dual-boots OSX and Ubuntu.
- SSID1 router is a LynkSys WRT54GL which I've flashed with DD-WRT micro build 12548M.
- Network SSID1 is setup to mimic that at Uni, where I need a 192.168.0.x IP range and the SSID must match what we use in our lab.
- Network SSID1 IPs are 192.168.0.x
- Network SSID2 IPs are 172.20.10.x/15

**What I've tried so far**

- I've tried setting up a static route in the SSID1 router to forward traffic to PC1.  The packets are forwarded to PC1 but stop there.
- I've tried Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) on PC1's Wireless connection but it wants to (1) establish a DHCP server (which SSID1 router already has), and (2) change the IP range (which I am able to modify back to what I need) but neither the Nao nor PC1 are able to reach the internet.  It also changes SSID1 network to type *Public Network* which creates Windows Firewall related problems for me (and I've turned that off for now) and doesn't actually share anything.
- I've tried Bridging PC1's SSID1 Network LAN connection to the SSID2 Network via WiFi.  This changes the IP of the network to match my iPhone's DHCP server range (which I cannot change), but PC2 can't even reach PC1 now.
- I've tried connecting my iPhone via a USB cable to PC1, and then Bridging/ICS on that network device, but using USB instead of WiFi doesn't seem to matter.

**I have't tried yet**

- Implementing the bridge in the router, as I'm concerned that this will take away my ability to mimic the Uni's network.  But I'll try that after I get some sleep.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I can supply further information; details of what I've tried and my settings, if requested.

*I will update the title once I get a better idea of what the actual problem is.*